# Report Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a report in SSRS 2008 R2, which shows a "calendar" of training sessions.

Let me give an example:

I have a session that has a start date and an end date, and has a start time and an end time.
I wanted to create a table in which the columns were the days of the month, and the lines were hours, in my case, 8 AM, 9 AM ...

The objective would be something like this:

[image: Example]

I have a table where I can get all sessions, with a start date, with the start time and the end time.

My concern relapsed on the following aspects:

- You will need a table with Year, Month, Day?
- What about Ace hours? Also should I have some table? Or create table directly in the Report?

I'm out of ideas to solve this problem, and would like to know some opinions and if possible do this in Reporting Services.

Regards.

**FIRST EDIT:**

I have this table with data sessions:

```
idSession  | nameSession | startDate  |        startTime      |        endTime       | 
    1      |   module 1  | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01 09:00:00   |  2013-01-01 09:00:00 |
    2      |   module 2  | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01 14:00:00   |  2013-01-01 18:00:00 |
    3      |   module 3  | 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-01 09:00:00   |  2013-01-02 09:00:00 |
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but perhaps I can help you clarify your question. Is it correct that you have a database table with information about each session? If so, please show the table structure and some sample data. And is your goal to produce a report that looks like the image you have above?

Comment: @Pondlife thanks for the reply. I edited the question, I added some information there that asked me.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar report, and it was a struggle. Ultimately I created a main report for the column and row headers (hours and days), with a subreport to show the detail. So I created a dataset to list each hour value (select '8:00' union select '8:30' union...etc) and used that as my row value. The column header is calculated based on a prompted date--so the first column would be the date selected, the second column is the selected date plus one day, etc. for a total of 6 columns since we typically run the report for Mon-Sat. The nested detail report selects from the db table based on the hour and date values passed from the main report.

Comment: your report was for the whole month? You could have several months?
The times were in the database?

Comment: Yes, the times were in the database, though I ended up creating a derived column to pull out the start and end hour--just made coding easier. So if an event ended at say 1:45, it appears on the calendar through 2:00, but I included the start and end times in the text that appeared for each event. My report only displays a week--do you need several months?

Comment: Yes, because it can take two or three months. With what you said, I get some ideas, but it will be very complicated to develop something.

Comment: I think I have a better solution for you--create a matrix with hard coded hours across the top columns, and use the date field as your row group. Each hour's data field would be an expression that will show the name of the event if the hour matches--something like: IIF(Fields!StartHour.Value <= 8 And Fields!EndHour.Value >= 8, Fields!ActivityName.Value, ""). A little cumbersome to set up, but it worked for me. The number of days/months won't matter because it will group for each day in the date range you enter. Make sense?

Comment: For the part of using the expressions, yes, it would be the way I would do. However, we still don't know how I'll get the days of the month, as well as their hours, knowing that I only have the table with the information (you can see in the first edit).

Comment: Do you mean how to get the days and hours from your data? Or how to get the heading date and time values on the matrix?

Comment: Depending on the data table that I have, I do not see how I can get it all (both dates as hours)

Comment: I had to hard code the hours as the column headers, then using the datepart function get the start and end hour. The date (row group) would populate based on your database field--startdate I guess? Though you could run into a problem if there was a date with no activity. In our case there is a calendar table with every day of the year so we can outer join to get all the days.

Comment: I'm trying to sort it all through a procedure. the hours I put in a table.

Comment: I'm still trying to solve my problem. I left a question here, if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688467/sql-query-hourly-for-each-day