# Query to return all the days of a month

Tags: sql, sql-server

This problem is related to this, which has no solution in sight: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548703/report-schedule/15554016?noredirect=1#comment22044254_15554016)

I have a table that shows me all sessions of an area.

This session has a start date.

I need to get all the days of month of the start date of the session by specific area (in this case)

I have this query:

```
SELECT idArea, idSession, startDate FROM SessionsPerArea WHERE idArea = 1

idArea | idSession |  startDate  |
   1   |    1      |  01-01-2013 |
   1   |    2      |  04-01-2013 |
   1   |    3      |  07-02-2013 |
```

And i want something like this:

```
    date     |  Session    |
01-01-2013   |    1        |
02-01-2013   |    NULL     |
03-01-2013   |    NULL     |
04-01-2013   |    1        |
........     |             |
29-01-2013   |   NULL      |
30-01-2013   |   NULL      |
```

In this case, the table returns me all the days of January.

The second column is the number of sessions that occur on that day, because there may be several sessions on the same day.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I strongly recommend using [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to represent dates in your code.

Comment: The dates are for example. but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
DECLARE @SessionsPerArea TABLE (idArea INT, idSession INT, startDate DATE)
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES
(1,1,'2013-01-01'),
(1,2,'2013-01-04'),
(1,3,'2013-07-02')

;WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT  startDate
            , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate), '1900-01-01') firstInMonth
            , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate) + 1, '1900-01-01')) lastInMonth
            , COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM    @SessionsPerArea
    WHERE   idArea = 1
    GROUP BY
            startDate
)
, calendar AS
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) d
    FROM    t1 
    JOIN    master..spt_values c ON
            type = 'P'
    AND     DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) BETWEEN t1.firstInMonth AND t1.lastInMonth
)

SELECT  d date
        , cnt Session
FROM    calendar c
LEFT    JOIN t1 ON t1.startDate = c.d
```

It uses simple join on `master..spt_values` table to generate rows.

Comment: The problem is that I do not need all those dates, only needed on-month session.

Comment: You can try it now, it shows count for sessions on a date. You want only records for months in which sessions happened?

Comment: I want the days of every month in which there is a session.
If there is no session I do not want this month.
But I still have 2048 rows. In my case, I just want the month of January.

Comment: I updated my answer, it returns records only for those month that have some sessions.

Comment: Shouldn't it also return days for the 7. month since there is a session in 7.?

Comment: Yes... I think that with this solution now can go a little.

Comment: One more question, why forcing the date 01/01/2013?

Comment: You can put any date as your first date, as long as the dates that you want to retrieve are within the first date and next 5 years (next 2048 days from the first date, to be more precise)...

Comment: instead of putting "01/01/2013", can I put the date of the first session?

Comment: After some tests, matches what I needed. thank you. will answer some needs.

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @SessionsPerArea TABLE (idArea INT, idSession INT, startDate DATEtime)
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES (1,1,'2013-01-01')
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES (1,2,'2013-01-04')
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES (1,3,'2013-07-02')

DECLARE @RepMonth as datetime
SET @RepMonth = '01/01/2013';
WITH DayList (DayDate) AS
(
    SELECT @RepMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, DayDate)
    FROM DayList
    WHERE (DayDate < DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 1, @RepMonth)))
)
SELECT *
FROM DayList t1 left join @SessionsPerArea t2 on t1.DayDate=startDate and t2.idArea = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but where is "t2.DayDate=startDate" the startDate? which refers to?

Comment: Sorry... it was a mistake... plz check.

Comment: It is not entirely correct, because I wanted to return me all the days of that month. I do not want the previous month and this way it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of calendar table. To return data for a month adjust the number of days between < 32, for a year to 365+1. You can calculate the number of days in a month or between start/end dates with query. I'm not sure how to do this in SQL Server. I'm using hardcoded values to display all dates in Jan-2013. You can adjust start and end dates for diff. month or to get start/end dates with queries...:

```
WITH data(r, start_date) AS 
(
 SELECT 1 r, date '2012-12-31' start_date FROM any_table --dual in Oracle
  UNION ALL
 SELECT r+1, date '2013-01-01'+r-1 FROM data WHERE r < 32 -- number of days between start and end date+1
)
 SELECT start_date FROM data WHERE r > 1
/

START_DATE
----------
1/1/2013
1/2/2013
1/3/2013
...
...
1/31/2013
```