# get all day of month then mapping data to specific date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a chart that will plot data to show value for present data on specific date

with this SQL

```
select substring(TRAN_DATE, 1, 4) MONTH, substring(TRAN_DATE, 5, 2) DATE, count(*) AMOUNT from  TA1606 group by TRAN_DATE
```

this is field structure

```
 TRAN_DATE  char(6)
```

with this create command

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TA16](
    [TRAN_DATE] [char](6) NULL,
    [TERM] [char](16) NULL,
)
```

this my result is

```
MONTH   DATE    AMOUNT
1606    03        44
```

but this is just only one row and one day
i need to get all day of month in example is `06` `June` it will query all day in the month then mapping data to `date` as my result above shown

this is my expected result

```
    MONTH   DATE    AMOUNT
1606          1     0
1606          2     0
1606          3     44
1606          4     0
1606          5     0
1606          6     0
1606          7     0
1606          8     0 
1606          9     0
1606          10    0
1606          11    0
1606          12    0
1606          13    0
1606          14    0
1606          15    0
1606          16    0
1606          17    0
1606          18    0
1606          19    0
1606          20    0
1606          21    0
1606          22    0
1606          23    0
1606          24    0
1606          25    0
1606          26    0
1606          27    0
1606          28    0
1606          29    0
1606          30    0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL and sample data as DML. Also, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: I Updated a question

Comment: And I've retracted my downvote :-)

Comment: my uncleared question was just like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570627/query-to-return-all-the-days-of-a-month

Comment: your article you gave will be my treasure :)

Comment: I'd recommend Aaron's articles every day :-) He has a series of articles called Bad habits to kick, everyone of them that I've read was great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the idea is to use a left join between a calendar table and your data table.
There are many ways to create a calendar table, I like to use a tally table for that.
So the First thing you should do, if you don't already have a tally table, is to [create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table).
If you are asking your self what is a tally table and why do you need it, [read this article by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

```
SELECT TOP 1001 IDENTITY(int,0,1) AS Number
    INTO Tally
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
ALTER TABLE Tally ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Now, Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your next question)

```
DECLARE @TA16 TABLE (
    [TRAN_DATE] [char](6) NULL,
    [TERM] [char](16) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TA16 VALUES ('160603', '44')
```

Then, Use a [`CTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to create a calendar for the relevant year (or month, what ever is best for you),
And since you are using char to keep the date, we need another cte to [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) that char value to proper date.

```
;With Calendar as
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number, '2016-01-01') TheDate
    FROM Tally 
    WHERE Number < 367 -- Most years are 365 days, but leap years are 366, so it will cover leap years as well
), TA16WithActualDate AS
(
    SELECT  [TRAN_DATE], 
            [TERM],
            CONVERT(date, LEFT([TRAN_DATE], 2) +'.'+ SUBSTRING ([TRAN_DATE], 3, 2) +'.'+ RIGHT([TRAN_DATE], 2), 2) As ActualDate
    FROM @TA16
)
```

Now, select from `Calendar` [left joined](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) to the `TA16WithActualDate` cte and format the output as you wish:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(char(5), TheDate, 2), '.', '') As [Month],  
        RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 2), 2) As [Date],
        ISNULL([TERM], 0) As Amount
FROM Calendar
LEFT JOIN TA16WithActualDate ON TheDate = TRAN_DATE
WHERE MONTH(TheDate) = 6
```

Results:

```
Month Date Amount
--- ---- ------
1606  01   0               
1606  02   0               
1606  03   44              
1606  04   0               
1606  05   0               
1606  06   0               
1606  07   0               
1606  08   0               
1606  09   0               
1606  10   0               
1606  11   0               
1606  12   0               
1606  13   0               
1606  14   0               
1606  15   0               
1606  16   0               
1606  17   0               
1606  18   0               
1606  19   0               
1606  20   0               
1606  21   0               
1606  22   0               
1606  23   0               
1606  24   0               
1606  25   0               
1606  26   0               
1606  27   0               
1606  28   0               
1606  29   0               
1606  30   0
```

Comment: your answer was absolutely clear :) and work like a charm, thank your very much

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 substring(TRAN_DATE, 1, 4) MONTH
    ,substring(TRAN_DATE, 5, 2) DATE
    ,count(*) AMOUNT
FROM TA1606
GROUP BY TRAN_DATE
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

This query would probably give result like this.

```
MONTH   DATE  AMOUNT
1606   3     44
```

Comment: your code show me just

`Month DATE AMOUNT`
`16June 03 44`

Comment: What's your expected result.

Comment: my expected result was under "I need them to show as this"

my difinite result was just  `1606    03        44`

Comment: Your are expecting only one row with Amount>0 right