# SQL query hourly for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question that seems to be quite complex. I needed to know what happens in a session that day, at a certain time.

Briefly I have a table that shows me all sessions of a given area. These sessions have a start date and a start time and an end time.

You can see in this table:

```
idArea | idSession |  startDate  |    startTime        |    endTime  
   1   |    1      |  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 1900-01-01 12:00:00
   1   |    2      |  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 14:00:00 | 1900-01-01 15:00:00
   1   |    3      |  2013-01-04 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 1900-01-01 13:00:00
   1   |    4      |  2013-01-07 | 1900-01-01 10:00:00 | 1900-01-01 12:00:00
   1   |    5      |  2013-01-07 | 1900-01-01 13:00:00 | 1900-01-01 18:00:00
   1   |    6      |  2013-01-08 | 1900-01-01 10:00:00 | 1900-01-01 12:00:00
```

Then I also have a table that shows me all hours interspersed, ie every half hour (I created this table on purpose for this requirement, if someone has a better idea, I can say that I will try to adapt).

```
idHour |   Hour
   1   |   1900-01-01 00:00:00
   2   |   1900-01-01 00:30:00
   3   |   1900-01-01 01:00:00
  ............................
   4   |   1900-01-01 09:00:00
   5   |   1900-01-01 09:30:00
   6   |   1900-01-01 10:00:00
   7   |   1900-01-01 10:30:00
  ............................
```

In the end that's what I want to present was this:

```
  startDate  |    startTime        |    SessionID
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 09:30:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 10:00:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 10:30:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 11:00:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 11:30:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 11:30:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 14:00:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 14:30:00 |        1
  2013-01-01 | 1900-01-01 15:00:00 |        1
```

This table is only for idSession=1 what I wanted was for all sessions. If there are no sessions for one day can return NULL.

The hard this query or procedure, is that they have to show me all the days of the month when there are sessions for that area.

For this, I already used this query:

```
;WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT  
        startDate,
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate), '1900-01-01') firstInMonth,
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate) + 1, '1900-01-01')) lastInMonth,
        COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM    
        @SessionsPerArea
    WHERE
        idArea = 1
    GROUP BY
        startDate
), calendar AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) d
    FROM    
        t1 
    JOIN
        master..spt_values c ON type = 'P'
                             AND DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) BETWEEN t1.firstInMonth AND t1.lastInMonth
)
SELECT  
    d date, 
    cnt Session
FROM
    calendar c
LEFT JOIN 
    t1 ON t1.startDate = c.d
```

It is quite complex, if anyone has an easy way to do this was excellent.

Comment: If there are multiple sessions for a given time period what output do you expect?  One row for each time and session?  One row for the time with a list of sessions?

Comment: That doesn't seem that complex to me considering what you're doing.

Comment: @HABO Yes, one row for each time and session. It seems to be the best solution for this output.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud For me it is.

Comment: @PookPook, I'm merely stating that I'm not sure it can really be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is simply a join between the calendar table and @SessionPerArea,w ith the right conditions:

```
select spa.StartDate, c.hour as StartTime, spa.idSession as SessionId
from calendar c join
     @SessionsPerArea spa
     on c.hour between spa.startTime and spa.EndTime
```

The join is matching all times between the start and end times in the data, and then returning the values.

Comment: But in this case only those returns that are equal. In this case for 09:00:00 and 14:00:00. half an hour will not show up.

Comment: @PookPook . . . In your question, you say that the calendar table has data for every half hour.  So, each half hour should show up.

Comment: I just finished testing and is almost perfect.
Only issue is that it does not return all days of the month. At issue even has a SQL query that returns me all the days of the month, according to SessionArea.
If there could appear NULL sessions.

Comment: @PookPook . . . It should return all the days and times that are in the calendar table.

Comment: but if you see a query that I present, it returns me all the days of the month. The question is, if there is no session one day, just returns me a line with the date and the rest may appear as NULL.

Comment: However the query is excellent. only lacked even this detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you simply need an outer join between calendar and @SessionsPerArea...so all the days in the calendar table are returned regardless of a match to the @SessionsPerArea table?

Comment: Dont return all the days of the month.

Comment: Your calendar table includes each day, correct? So this is not returning all the dates? select spa.StartDate, c.hour as StartTime, spa.idSession as SessionId
from calendar c left outer join
     @SessionsPerArea spa
     on c.hour between spa.startTime and spa.EndTime

Comment: No. My table calendar only returns the hours.